# Angular and .Net Core API - TV control for viewing dashboard which is assigned by MAC address

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, mac-address

I have a requirement as to create a TV control in my existing Angular based dashboard application which is driven by .Net Core API. More specifically, I need a feature for assigning MAC address to a dashboard for viewing the dashboard in the TV control. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and study what I have found that we cannot get the MAC address from the machine where the browser is running on by executing JavaScript/Angular inside the browser. Access to this information is restricted due to the sandbox in which JavaScript/Angular is executed. That means it would be a privacy/security vulnerability if we would be able to do this directly from JavaScript/Angular.

However, we can get the IP address instead of the MAC address and thus I have found a work around regarding my problem I have posted here.